# MapBox - How to disable all movement in mapbox-gl-js except rotation and zoom to a set point

Tags: javascript, typescript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I 'am trying to disable all movement of the map, except rotation and zoom to a set point.
But on a touch device I can still move the 'camera' from the set point with two fingers, it works fine on a non touch device.

This is what I currently have, and that is not fully working I can still move the camera center point with two fingers on a touch device. I 'am using typescript with ionic/angular.

```js
this.map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: 'game_map',
      style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/light-v10',
      center: [coords],
      zoom: 20,
      touchZoomRotate: {around: 'center'},
      scrollZoom: {around: 'center'},
      pitch: 60,
      bearing: -60,
      antialias: true,
      attributionControl: false,
      maxZoom: 22,
      minZoom: 17
    });
```

Answer (score 5):

You can disable user panning by adding:

```
 dragPan: false,
```

to that initialisation statement. [More info](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map).

Comment: I still can move the map with two fingers on a touch device...

Comment: You can still drag to pan even when `dragPan` is set false? Sounds like a bug.

Comment: Yes I can still drag is, but only with two fingers on a touch device not on a desktop

Comment: I suggest you raise an issue. That doesn't sound like the correct behaviour. https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/new?template=Bug_report.md

Comment: Created the issue. https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/9359